# Typescript not recognizing checks from function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that validates input

```
export const isValidString = (value: string | null | undefined): boolean => {
  return value != null && value.length > 0 && value.trim() != "";
};

const func = (input: string) =>{
  // some code
}

const someFunction = (input : string | null | undefined) => {
   if(isValidString(input)){
     func(input); //This is the line that is complaining
  }
};
```

the call to the func is throwing an error which I'm not sure why as the `isValidString` is making sure the input is not undefined. Any reason why ?

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

However, if I just do

```
if(input != null) func(input);
```

Everything works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `isValidString()` only returns a `boolean`, typescript does not know that you have checked that your type is a `string` now.

E.g. when you hoover over the `input` variable in this [typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wJaoGoEMA2GAJgMoxQbIDmcAvHABQBuBArsAFxzoXVwA%20cZK3z4BcVsiLAAZpWBEAlFwBGECPmC5kdAHxwA3gCg4puFGAxWUHS3zs4AQnrDRcAGTu4d9gDpN1DAAFnD6AAweXj7AvuQYALYMik70AESpANxGAL5ZSGjwMpIIdIyUYKwwXDyUVMm0%20sZmcAD0LagQ8cCIENI5Rvno3J3AAGLFMBgopQzlldVxfIKuYoKS0nLICvWNJmYYMmU4BMRkvFSzyBUwislNzWZFyAiX14oZrS0AKkFYcH-BbqELZwYK4TCoHrxMD4XCUWp7UzZIw5DJAA), you can see that the type is still `string | undefined | null`
[image]

To change that, your function must be a [type-guard](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-type-guards/)

```js
export const isValidString = (value: string | null | undefined): value is string => {
```

Note, the return type of the function is now `value is string`

When you hoover over `input` in the [new example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wJaoGoEMA2GAJgMoxQbIDmcAvHABQBuBArsAFxzoXVwA%20cZK3z4BcVsiLAAZpWBEAlFxb52cLN3KUatAHxwA3gCg4ZuFGAxWUZHFXqAhPWGi4AMnf22wAHT5gahgACzgDAAYPLwc-bQBbBkU4ZzgAIlSAbmMAXyykNHgZSQQ6RkowVhguHh0k-SNTcwB6JtQIOOBECGkc43z0bnbgADFimAwUUoZyyurtPkFXMUFJaTlkBTqDE3MNGTKcAmIyXipp5AqYRSSd3fMi5ARzy8UMuBaAFWDNTRDOwg2cBCuEwqC6cTA%20FwlB0jTM2WMOQyQA), you can see that the type is now `string`

Comment: Thank you, totally makes more sense now.